# Unable to pull Net Suite custom record values through Restlet : (Error: SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COL)

Tags: netsuite

I'm running with a strange issue here. Haven't up fronted with any issue with `Netsuite Restlet` earlier while pulling the field values.But suddenly I encountered with a strange issue here. I have a custom record and it has almost 20 fields and previously my restlet was able to pull all the information correctly. And now I added one extra field but I was totally surprised, I was unable to put it in search column.

```
var Filters = [];
Filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('custrecord_name', null, 'anyof', dataIn.gId);
Filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'is', dataIn.rId);

var Columns = [];
Columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('name');
Columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_name');
Columns[2] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_type');
 .
 .
 .
 .
Columns[13] = new nlobjSearchColumn('custrecord_service_name'); // getting error


var rCatResults = nlapiSearchRecord('customrecord_service_category', null, Filters, Columns);
```

It is throwing error.

`Error: SSS_INVALID_SRCH_COL
An nlobjSearchColumn contains an invalid column, or is not in proper syntax:`

However I'm well acquainted with `nlobjSearchFilter` and `nlobjSearchColumn`. I double checked with the field `internal id` and its working fine in debugger but I'm getting the above error while calling through `rest`. Does anybody have any idea why it is throwing this error ??

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you might be seeing this error. However, I've noticed that one of your filters is on `internalid`, so you should never have more than one result. A different approach might be to use `nlapiLoadRecord(dataIn.rId)` instead of doing a search. For custom records, this would only use 2 units instead of the 10 for a search, and you would get access to all the fields on the record without having to specify those that you want.

Comment: @egrubaugh360   Yes,I agree. But here my scenario was a bit twisted which promoted me to do so. Actually I already had an implemented restlet and I had to just add one additional field into it. If i would have gone with `nlapiLoadRecord` then I had to retrieve only selected field values which I wanted in my response and then create a JSON but as it is already implemented so I didn't want to change the response structure thats why I continued with the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the exact same issue and there was no real error in the search column syntax but there seems to be a very frustrating Netsuite bug that makes the search error out when you add a new field to a custom record form while logged in as the current user.  When I logged out and logged back in with the same user the search column worked perfectly fine as if there were never any error to begin with.

Comment: yep this worked for me. I added a custom field, before my session ends i tried searching record and caught the error. But when i logout and logged in again it works.

Comment: I am having the same error, but logging in and out of my session does not work for me. Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Check a couple of things first..

1. Field permissions, might be that the user running the rest request doesn't have access to that field.
2. Field data type, could be you are searching for something which NS doesn't know how to respond.
3. Syntax, maybe you put a letter in the wrong place and didn't noticed.

Comment: Thanks for your response @pipechang. I already checked what you have mentioned and everything is fine. However I'm curious to find out the reason. I did the same with a different login then it works like a charm. But the point is that both the account have the same role permission. I tried to add a new field in another record in the previous login and it was working fine for me. I didn't understand only for that particular record why it is throwing an error.

Comment: Check for user level permissions.